# Instead of email the user id going into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Been trying for hours anyways this form suppose to take my email that is being displayed and  on submit inserts the details include email into database.
[image: Form]

Instead of taking my 'email' it is taking my user id(auto increment) from user table and update that into feedback table.[image: database]

**feedback.php**

```
<?php   


$email =(isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : null);
$name='';$feedback=''; $topic=''; $details=''; 
$action =(isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : null);

if($action!=null) {                 

    $name =(isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null);
    $feedback =(isset($_POST['feedback']) ? $_POST['feedback'] : null);
    $topic =(isset($_POST['topic']) ? $_POST['topic'] : null);
    $details =(isset($_POST['details']) ? $_POST['details'] : null)

    if($details==null) {
        echo "<br><p style='text-align:center;color:red'>Please fill up all text fields!</p>";
    }
    else {
        $query="insert into feedback values('','$email','$name','$feedback','$topic','$details','',null)";
        $result=mysql_query($query);


        echo "<br><p style='text-align:center;color:blue'>Successfully submit the feedback to system </p>";
        $feedback=''; $topic=''; $details=''; 
    }

    if( mysql_error()!="") {
        echo "<font style='text-align:center;color:red'>" . mysql_error() . "</font><br>"; 
    } 


}
?>


<form method="post" action="user_feedback.php">     
    <?php
    $email =(isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : null);
    $query="select * from user where id=$email";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    ?>
    <br>
    <table cellpadding="5">
            <tr><td style="width:150px">User Email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>" disabled style="width:200px;"  ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" style="width:300px;" ></td></tr>

    <tr><td>Feedback</td>
    <td>
        <select name="feedback" style="height:32px">            
        <option <?php if($feedback=="Inquiry") { echo 'selected'; } ?> >Inquiry</option>

        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Feedback Topic</td><td><input type="text" name="topic" value="<?php echo $topic ?>" style="width:300px;" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Feedback Details</td><td><textarea type="comment" name="details" value="<?php echo $details ?>" style="width:500px;" ></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="tall"></td></tr>
    </table>


</form>
```

Comment: You don't even use `$_POST['email']` in your code.

Comment: I have tried adding `$email =(isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);`
after `if($action!=null) {` but then my database email column is empty not even id is shown

Comment: what's the value of your `$_SESSION['email']`? And why are you referring your `id` for `email` on this query `$query="select * from user where id=$email";`

Comment: The problem is fixed now, thank you guys.
@dexterb by looking at your suggestion I have tried `echo("{$_SESSION['email']}");` and it return me id and changed to `echo("{$_SESSION['id']}");` it returned me email. Btw the reason for using `$query="select * from user where id=$email";` because my login uses this `$_SESSION['email'] = $row['id']; 
     $_SESSION['logged_in'] = $_POST['id'];`


Didn't use any POST method for email like @tkausl suggested but my email went through. I think I have mixed up login session between email and id.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by using suggestion because there is was mixed up of login session between id and email on login page it self.

```
<?php   

//echo("{$_SESSION['id']}"."<br />");

$email =(isset($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : null);  
$name='';$feedback=''; $topic=''; $details=''; 
$action =(isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : null);
if($action!=null) {                 

    $name =(isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null);
    $feedback =(isset($_POST['feedback']) ? $_POST['feedback'] : null);
    $topic =(isset($_POST['topic']) ? $_POST['topic'] : null);
    $details =(isset($_POST['details']) ? $_POST['details'] : null);

    if($topic==null || $details==null) {
        echo "<br><p style='text-align:center;color:red'>Please fill up all text fields!</p>";
    }
    else {
        $query="insert into feedback values('','$email','$name','$feedback','$topic','$details','',null)";
        $result=mysql_query($query);


        echo "<br><p style='text-align:center;color:blue'>Successfully submit the feedback to system </p>";
        $feedback=''; $topic=''; $details=''; 
    }

    if( mysql_error()!="") {
        echo "<font style='text-align:center;color:red'>" . mysql_error() . "</font><br>"; 
    } 


}
?>  

<form method="post" action="user_feedback.php">     
    <?php
    $email =(isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : null);
    $query="select * from user where id=$email";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    ?>
    <br>
    <table cellpadding="5">
            <tr><td style="width:150px">User Email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>" disabled style="width:200px;"  ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" style="width:300px;" ></td></tr>

    <tr><td>Feedback</td>
    <td>
        <select name="feedback" style="height:32px">            
        <option <?php if($feedback=="Inquiry") { echo 'selected'; } ?> >Inquiry</option>

        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Feedback Topic</td><td><input type="text" name="topic" value="<?php echo $topic ?>" style="width:300px;" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Feedback Details</td><td><textarea type="comment" name="details" value="<?php echo $details ?>" style="width:500px;" ></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="tall"></td></tr>
    </table>


</form>
```